# Cannot resolve / reject a Promise

Tags: typescript, api, es6-promise, restify

I wrote a `service` method which allow an `user` to get a authenticate in my restify `API`. The get method invoke this:

```
public async auth(email: string, password: string): Promise<Customer> {
    let connection = await DatabaseProvider.getConnection();
    const customer = await connection.getRepository(Customer).findOne({ email });

    try {
        let isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, customer!.password);

        if (!isMatch) throw 'Password did not match';
        Promise.resolve(customer);
    } catch (err) {
        Promise.reject('Authentication failed');
    }
}
```

the problem's that I get:

> A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

seems that `Promise.resolve(customer)` does not return anything, I also tried to prefix with `return` but same problem

Comment: It doesn't return anything, no, it just *creates* a resolved promise. Why not just `return customer;` and `throw 'Authentication failed';`, instead, given that an `async` function already returns a promise anyway?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the hint! I'm a newbie to `TypeScript`. I apply your suggestions and now I get on `return customer` this error: `Type 'Customer | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Customer'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Customer'`

Comment: That's not TypeScript, just JS. And I guess you get that because findOne returns a Customer or undefined if not found, so you need to handle that second case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe okay, I actually fixed it using ` Promise<Customer | undefined>` is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know, it's up to you to decide the API for the function. Do you want the consumer to receive a revolved promise of undefined or a rejected promise if the customer isn't found, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public async auth(email: string, password: string): Promise<Customer> {
    let connection = await DatabaseProvider.getConnection();

    const customer = await connection.getRepository(Customer).findOne({ email });

    let isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, customer!.password);

    if (!isMatch) throw 'Password did not match';

    if(customer)
      return customer;

    throw 'Customer is undefined';
}
```

This should work i guess...